# Corrupt JPEG Data: 1273 extraneous bytes before marker. Opencv 3/python2.7

Tags: python, opencv, camera, raspberry-pi, usb

This is the code when i execute it:
[You can see the frame opens but doesnt show anything](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JsUwC.png)

I want to use a usb camera with a raspberry pi 3 model b v1.2 using opencv 3.3 and python 2.7.

I work with opencv in an virtual enviroment.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while(True):
    ret, frame = cap.read() #Capture frame-by-frame

    #Our operations on the frame come here
    #gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    #Display resulting frame
    cv2.imshow('frame',frame)
    cv2.waitKey(10)
    #if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
    #   break

#when everything done, release the capture
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I just have no idea how to get around this error. I already searched the error and i am getting helpless, anyone having an idea?

EDIT: i am currently playing around with the code and i can get frames but most of the time the screen stays grey. I use # to show how the code looks now

Comment: I really have no idea what you're asking or what an answer should look like. Please can you reword this to a clear question? Please see [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: well i have a error and i have no idea how to fix it.

Comment: Please try to minimize the noise (everything unrelated to the problem), and **write** the error **in** the question, not posted as an image

Comment: yes i will, thanks for the feedback. Its my first question on stackoverflow

Comment: Try commenting out the line starting `gray=...` and `cv2.imshow...` etc so that the only line you run is `cap.read()` and see if you still get an error. Then at least we will know where the error is.

Comment: if i comment everything exept read() i only get the corrupt jpeg data error. Not even the Warning that showed up in the image

Comment: You could try acquiring some data using the `raspivid` command-line and seeing if you can play that back on another system, to see if the data really are corrupt.

Comment: you know i am not using the raspberry pi camera but a special usb camera that can be used as a microscope

Comment: Ok i am now officially confused. I tried playing around with the code and the cap.set() function doesnt seem to work. Error is "NameError: name 'CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT' is not defined". But cv2 is included and installed. I dont understand how it cant be recognized

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it now opens a window and shows the output of the camera

Because of this code:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/home/pi/.virtualenvs/cv/lib/python2.7/site-
packages/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages')
```

and i also use sudo python program.py in the terminal

But this Error :"NameError: name 'CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT' is not defined" still persists...